# Unsigned long Int in Core data

Tags: swift

I have an Entity with attribute of type Int64. But, I need to save an object with type Unsigned Long Int or unsigned long long Int. How can I do it?
Swift, please (:

Comment: Can't you just cast it to `UInt64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
let x = Int64(5) //Int64
let y = CUnsignedLongLong(bitPattern: x) //Unsigned Long Long
```